# How to access a subclass members

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm having trouble accessing the data members of the subclass Node.

```
template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node * parent;

        Node() :left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL) {};
        Node(const T& item) {
            data = item;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
            parent = NULL;
        };
    };
```

I'm trying to write two functions for this binary search tree getHeight() and getSize(), however I need to access the right and left nodes (or children) of the binary search tree in order to calculate it. Here is the code I've writen trying to attempt this:

```
template <class T>
int BinarySearchTree<T>::getHeight() const {
    //TODO
    int number = 0;
    Node * heightNode = new Node();
    heightNode = _root;
    if (left == NULL && right == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        number = max(right->height(), left->height()) + 1;
    }
    return height;
}
```

My thought process is to descend down both subtrees and return the max of each subtree to count the height.

```
template <class T>
int BinarySearchTree<T>::getSize() const {
    // TODO
    int size;
    if (){
        return 0;
    }
    inorderHelper(cout, this->Node->left); //L 
    size++;                               //V
    inorderHelper(cout, this->Node->right);//R
    return size;
}
```

Here my thought process is to perform an in order traversal on the binary search tree, incrementing size for each node.

Comment: `Node * heightNode = new Node(); heightNode = _root;` -- leak much?

Comment: How so? I should be making the heightNode equal to the root.

Comment: Were you planning on saying the problem you're having? I don't see any subclasses here.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to access the node class which is a subclass of Binary Search tree. So far no luck. I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: @JakeBurns _"I'm having trouble ..."_ is obviously too narrow to ask here, to expect useful answers. Be clear about that _troubles_: Compiler errors, runtime exceptions, unexpected behavior (about clearly defined input and expected output). Voted to close your question as being unclear, and not being useful for future research.

Comment: `Node` is an _inner class_ **not** a _subclass_.

Comment: Still begs the question, how do I access Node?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access non-static members through the class type `Node` instead of accessing them through an instance of `Node`. Although you did not include enough relevant portions of `BinarySearchTree` it appears you have a member called `_root` which based on other code seems to be the root node in your tree. Assuming that is correct the following lines will need to be updated.

```
inorderHelper(cout, this->Node->left); //L 
size++;                               //V
inorderHelper(cout, this->Node->right);//R
```

...to something like this

```
inorderHelper(cout, _root->left); //L 
size++;                               //V
inorderHelper(cout, _root->right);//R
```

Unfortunately this will not give you the actual size of the tree since your code is incomplete.

You also have a memory leak in `getHeight()`. The following code creates an instance of `Node` but never deletes it before assigning `_root` to `heightNode`.

```
Node * heightNode = new Node();
heightNode = _root;
```

This should likely be changed to

```
Node * heightNode = _root;
```